# submit url without any special characters

Tags: c#, regex

i have a text box where the user will the url in it and submit that url (it takes that url and search in our db)

but before it hit the db i want to make sure that there is no special characters in it:

below is the regular expression i am using but still accepting the special characters

here are the special characters i am trying to avoid `< > % ( ) + ;`  these special caracters can be at the begining or end for an example:

()+;http://www.site.com/images.jpg()

for an example for ampersand (&) i use the below reg expression but somehow it ignores the begining.

```
Regex re = new Regex("\\(|\\)|\\<|\\>|\\\"|\\;|\n|\r|\\`|^&|&$");
```

so before i submit the above url i want to trip all the unwanted caracters.

```
static String StripSpcialChar(String param)        
{             
String result = null;             
if (param != null)             
{                                 
Regex re = new Regex("\\&|\\(|\\)|\\<|\\>|\\\"|\\;|\n|\r|\\`");                 
result = re.Replace(param, "");                 
result = result.Trim();             
}             
return result;         
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Are you trying to strip ALL matching characters, or just those at the beginning or end of the string?? And when you say "but somehow it ignores the begining", what do you mean? What happens with one code sample vs the other? (why do you have 2 different regex expressions here?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should cover the special characters you've specified and correctly strips an ampersand from the beginning or end of the string. To account for multiple ampersands at the beginning or end of the string you need to use `&+`, where the `+` matches one or more ampersand.

```
string input = "&&&()+;http://www.site.com/images.jpg()&&&";
Regex re = new Regex(@"[()<>"";+\n\r`]|^&+|&+$");
string result = re.Replace(input, "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Notice the use of the character class `[...]` which is much cleaner than multiple alternations with the pipe symbol. Within a character class there's no need to escape the characters. If you ever plan to match a dash you should place it at the beginning or end of the group to avoid accidentally specifying a range of characters. For example `[()<>"";+\n\r-]`.

Comment: if i try `http://www.site.com/foo.html&id=123&&&` then it dont trim the ampersand `&`

Comment: @Abu Hamzah: I updated the pattern to use `&+` so that one or more ampersand occurrence is matched. Try again with the new pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not want to escape parameters your self, it's better to **use built in escaping features** like placeholders or whatever your DB API in C# has.

See:

- http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx